# Как получить доступ к запущенному приложению с другого устройства внутри одной сети?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Речь идет о любом web-приложении, которое доступно после запуска, например, по `localhost:3000`.

Я хочу получить доступ к такому приложению с любого другого устройства, но если говорить конкретнее — с iPad. Нужно для тестирования.

*Я знаю что есть встроенные инструменты в браузеры для тестирования адаптивной верстки, но в данном случае речь идет не совсем о верстке. Да и если даже говорить про верстку, то на планшете посмотреть (имхо) легче и быстрее. Ну и про SKD тоже знаю, но все равно хочется реализовать доступ на физическом устройстве.*

Все устройства — включая и ноутбук, на котором ведется разработка и запуск приложения — находятся внутри одной сети, к которой подключаются с помощью Wi-Fi.

Но я не совсем понимаю как мне правильно настроить доступ.

Например, за ноутбуком внутри сети закреплен IP адрес — 192.168.1.60.
Я попытался прописать правило в NAT:

```
TCP, один порт: 3000
Перенаправить на адрес: 192.168.1.60
Порт назначения: 3000
```

Зашел в браузер на планшете, написал `192.168.1.60:3000` и ничего не вышло:

> Safari не удается открыть страницу, так как браузеру не удалось подключиться к серверу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Правило в NAT следует прописывать только для подключения из вне.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать правило NAT и зайти на `192.168.1.60:3000`

Comment: @V-Mor без NAT изначально пробовал. Если зайти просто по `192.168.1.60`, то я вижу `It works!`. Но если зайти на `192.168.1.60:3000`, то та же самая ошибка о невозможности подключиться к серверу. Сейчас удалил правило NAT - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Я полагаю, `It works` это корректный вывод Вашего приложения? Вы уверены, что Ваше приложение прослушивает именно порт 3000?

Comment: @V-Mor нет. У меня полноценное Rails приложение, в котором нет `It works!`. На самом ноутбуке именно `3000` порт. На нем все успешно работает и доступно.

Comment: Я не силён в RoR, однако в Django,  например, можно настроить сервер на прослушивание подключений по определённому IP. То есть, если Вы хотите слушать подключения по локальной сети, стоит установить прослушивание подключений на `192.168.1.60:3000`, если в RoR есть аналогичная возможность.

Comment: @V-Mor верно. Но разве в RoR и Django речь идет не о локальной среде? Например, в рамках одной машины (в моем случае ноутбука)? У меня сейчас идет прослушка `3000` порта. На ноутбуке все успешно работает. Но суть исходного поста в том, чтобы получить доступ к запущенному приложению на ноутбуке из вне (с другого устройства, с планшета, но внутри одной локальной сети).

Comment: @V-Mor я кажется понял о чем вы. Нашел вот это. Вы это имели ввиду? Сейчас попробую и отпишусь —  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132719/rails-application-not-visible-to-local-network

Comment: @Colibri Да, V-Mor писал об этом. Дело в том, что имя localhost обозначает Ip-адрес 127.0.0.1, который доступен только в пределах самой машины. И когда прослушивание идет на нем, то извне ничего не доступно. Прослушивание должно быть либо на явно заданном внешнем адресе (192.168...) что часто не удобно, либо 0.0.0.0 - который обозначает "на всех адресах этой машины"

Comment: @V-Mor да, вы были правы. Спасибо вам! Mike, и вам тоже спасибо :)

Comment: @Colibri Да, именно об этом. По примеру Django могу посоветовать `rails server --binding=192.168.1.60` или `rails server --binding=192.168.1.60:3000` чтобы не слушать всё и вся. Хотя это совсем не обязательно.

Comment: @Colibri Пожалуй, вынесу это в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правило в NAT следует прописывать только для подключения из вне.

Приложение следует настроить на прослушивание либо всех IP по порту 3000 (`rails server --binding=0.0.0.0`), либо именно подключений на  `192.168.1.60:3000` (`rails server --binding=192.168.1.60`).